# I'd like to use the "nested set model" but I'm obliged to have a GUID as primary key. How can I do without integers as pk?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, nested, hierarchical-data

I'm not **aware** how deep my tree will be. So I think the NSM is fit for me, reading some docs. In sql, this model suppose I'm using an integer value as primary key. I thought to create a twin table only to store the ints (PK,left,righ) connected by a relation one-to-one with the real table. Things are complicating and it is a waste of space disk, especially when the server is not mine and I have to pay each megabyte. Help!!

**UPDATE**

Excellent! Fabolous!! Thanks Macka and Bill, I could skip reading a whole book, for now.
Celko is a future order on Amazon. ;-)

Comment: What's NSM?  And also would you specify what version of SQL server you are running again?

Comment: NSM = Nested Set Model - see Joe Celko's post here: http://www.intelligententerprise.com/001020/celko.jhtml

Comment: @Macka: thanks.  time to learn about new stuff.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter what type your primary key is as the left/right values will still be integers. eg.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Demo](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Demo_ID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Lft] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Rgt] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Demo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

--add some test data

```
INSERT INTO demo(name,lft,rgt)
SELECT 'node1',1,6
UNION
SELECT 'node2a',2,3
UNION
SELECT 'node2b',4,5
```

--check it works

```
SELECT *
FROM demo
WHERE lft>=2
ORDER BY lft
```

Comment: thanks Macka. I'm going to do some query with fake data. Do you have any links where I can find an implementation ? I'm fresh with NSM, i need to improve my knowledge about it..

Comment: I'll just add that you want to make sure that you have proper constraints on your columns. For example, if you are not going to use a PK on lft and rgt at least add a unique index on it and also add a check constraint that lft < rgt

Comment: Joe Celko (who devised this) wrote a book called SQL for Smarties which covers this and some other cool ways of storing data - def. recommend that.  Start here http://www.intelligententerprise.com/001020/celko.jhtml and after that a Google search for 'Joe Celko' should have you sorted. Good luck!

Comment: Good point Tom.  Also, I ended up writing triggers which maintained the integrity of my tree (eg. lft/rgt values when inserting/moving/deleting)  It's okay having your app do this, but it only takes a "clever" developer in management studio to screw up your entire tree!

Comment: Some more links on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143226/cloning-hierarchical-data

Answer (score 1):

As @Macka [writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662697/id-like-to-use-the-nested-set-model-but-im-obliged-to-have-a-guid-as-primary-ke/662707#662707), the left and right values are not foreign keys to tree nodes, so they don't have to be the same type.  They can be integers while the tree node primary key is a GUID.

Celko also wrote "[Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202)" which goes into more detail about Nested Set Model, and other solutions.  Reading this book will save you a lot of time and a lot of mistakes.

There are other solutions to storing hierarchical data in a database.  See my answer here:
[What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)